# Observable Exception Handling with Directory.EnumerateFiles

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm a little confused with the following code:

Here is what I think should be happening

1. directorySearch is created as an observable but is not executed on since it's not been enumerated.
2. the Catch extension methods should be catching all the possible file system related errors, I have an extra Exception catch for debugging.

What is happening:

1. Exceptions are being thrown! :(

   ```
   var counter = 0;

   var directorySearch = Directory.EnumerateFiles("//.", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToObservable();

   directorySearch
           .Catch<string, DirectoryNotFoundException>(tx => Observable.Return(string.Empty))
           .Catch<string, UnauthorizedAccessException>(tx => Observable.Return(string.Empty))
           .Catch<string, PathTooLongException>(tx => Observable.Return(string.Empty))
           .Where(next => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(next))
           .Select(Path.GetFileName)
           .Do(_ => Debug.WriteLine("Logging, update some counter or something.."))
           .Do(_ => counter++)
           .Subscribe(_ => { Debug.WriteLine("File: " + _); });


       counter.Should().Be(18, "because there are that many files in the directory");
   ```

It seems like ToObservable is causing an enumeration to happen.

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Projects\DirectorySearching\SearchingSamples\SearchingSamples\bin\Debug\fake'.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
    at SearchingSamples.searching_samples_using_linq.reactive_showing_data_stream_processing() in searching_samples_using_linq.cs: line 47
```

Comment: can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: what is "fake" and where it is used?

Comment: Just a suggestion - don't do `counter++` - there's an overload on select that will give you the index number of the value produced by the observable so you don't have to rely on side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, the problem is because of the standard behavior of the `Directory` class, in this case the exception was thrown before `Observable.ToObservable(TSource)` method call.

The Rx way to fix it is "defering" the method execution, this technique is common used to transform a hot observable into a cold observable, which basically means that you will create a subscription side-effect.

```
var directorySearch = Observable.Defer(() => 
                                 Directory.EnumerateFiles("//.", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToObservable());
```

Answer (score 4):

ToObservable doesn't cause enumeration to happen.

Directory.EnumerateFiles will throw all by itself if the passed path is invalid. The [MSDN page for Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) documents this behavior:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: path is invalid, such as referring to an unmapped drive.